# Are wizards able to avoid Muggle detection after the invention of media cloud storage?

Tags: harry-potter, technology, muggles

We understand from the books that there are multiple parts of the Ministry of Magic and its counterparts devoted to deceiving Muggles, including concocting explanations for Muggle head of states in the event of magical catastrophes. We also know that Obliviators will wipe any Muggle's memory of such an accident.

But what happens when a Muggle takes a video or photo of a magical incident, which their phone then uploads to cloud storage? Even if you wiped the Muggle's memory and broke their phone, they'd still be able to access their cloud storage later, and upload the media to a sharing site.

Stopping a disaster like this has three parts:

1. Wizards have to know and understand how cloud storage works, including the idea of redundant backups among different servers. If the media is uploaded, they also have to understand how to find that media within every server that stores it.
2. Wizards have to be able to interface with computers via magic to correct the problem.
3. Wizards have to be able to find every Muggle that ever saw the media and obliviate them. If the media was uploaded to a sharing site, this could potentially be anything from a handful of people to hundreds of millions!

Alternately, wizards have to convince all Muggles that ever saw the media that it was fake. But if wizards can't solve parts 1-3, the problem will keep happening.

It seems to me there's no way wizards can avoid getting detected by Muggles once cloud storage becomes common, but am I missing something?

Comment: I'm unsure whether this is primarily opinion-based. We do have a lot of HP material, however it's all set before cloud storage.

Comment: As the technology described was not available at the time the books were written, I strongly suspect that a canonical in-universe answer cannot be given. Only speculation is possible, thus the question is PoB (primarily opinion-based)

Comment: @Jenayah I actually think it’s a duplicate, but the earlier question was closed as Primarily Opinion Based (though it’s not, in my opinion).

Comment: @eijen If you think your question is sufficiently different from the other one, you can [edit] to clarify how.